# How to scrape a website that's uses BankID for log in with Python (BeautifulSoap, Requests)?

Tags: python

How to scrape a website that's uses BankID for log in with Python (BeautifulSoap, Requests)?

I want to log in with BankID, then scrape a website with python. How do you log in to a website that uses BankID to log in?

The regular won't work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

source = requests.get('https://example.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way is to use `selenium`. Here is how u do it using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #Opens the chromedriver. If u don't have a chromedriver, u can download it from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads 

driver.get('Url of the banking website') #Opens the specified url

bank_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'Textbox xpath'))) #Finds the bank_id textbox 

bank_id.click() #Clicks it

bank_id.send_keys('Your username') #Enters ur username in the textbox
 
pswrd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Xpath of textbox') #Does the same for the password.

pswrd.click()

pswrd.send_keys('Your password')

login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Xpath of submit button') #Finds the login button

login_btn.click() #Clicks the login button
```

That's it! You have logged into the website! Hope that this helps!